# C# Class Design: strategy pattern with some classes that have caching functionality?

Tags: c#, class, design-patterns

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do this and I wanted to get some feedback.

### The Components

I have the following (simplified):

- An `Item`, which implements `IItem`
- A `Doodad`, which contains a `List<IItem>`
- An `IItemExistenceVerifier` interface which demands a `bool ItemExists(string ItemToCheck)`
- A `StandardCachedItemExistenceVerifier`, which includes a `FillCache(List<IITem> items)`
- A `DoodadValidator` which accepts an `IItemExitenceVerifier` and has a `Validate` method which calls `ItemExists(item)` for each item in the Doodad's list of items.

Attempt At a Diagram to express this:

[image: A class diagram attempting to illustrate the problem]

### The Goal

- I'd like to have a `StandardCachedItemExistenceVerifier` and a `StandardNonCachedItemVerifier` that I could pass in to the Doodad validator

### The Question/Problem

In the current structure:

- the validator will receive the `IItemExistenceVerifier` and will not know whether it uses a cache or not. The existence verifier will be newed up in advance and so I can't create a new verifier and pass the items in in the constructor).
- I can't always call `FillCache()` as part of the validation because it's not required by the interface.

### Potential Options

Maybe I could:

- Option 1: Implement `FillCache()` on even the `StandardNonCacheItemVerifier` and have it do nothing? (this seems like a smell)
- Option 2: In the validator, check to see if the `IItemExistenceVerifier` implements some other interface (`ICacheDrivenVerifier`) or something and then call `FillCache()` if it does?

  - Option 3: Something smarter than both of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usually stated by [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) in his [blog](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91), caching is a cross-cutting concern and thus can be solved using decorator. I don't know your final goal, but I assume it is `if the cache exists, use cache. If not, get from query and put in cache`.

What you need is to separate the operation into 2 class, one class to retrieve the object, and another to verify.

Here is an example:

```
public interface IItemRetriever{
    public IEnumerable<IItem> GetList();
}

public class StandardItemRetriever : IItemRetriever{
    public IEnumerable<IItem> GetList(){
        // returning the data
    }
}

public class CachedStandardItemRetriever : IItemRetriever{
    public CachedStandardItemRetriever(StandardItemRetriever standardItemRetriever){
        // property assignment
    }

    IEnumerable<IItem> items;
    public IEnumerable<IItem> GetList(){
        if(items == null || !items.Any())
        {
            items = this.standardItemRetriever.GetList();
        }
        return items;
    }
}

public class StandardItemExistanceVerifier{
    public StandardItemExistanceVerifier(IItemRetriever iItemRetriever){
        // property assignment
    }
}
```

With this, your verifier will only need to be injected by a `IItemRetriever`, in which can be standard or cached.

```
new StandardItemExistanceVerifier( new CachedStandardItemRetriever(new StandardItemRetriever()) );
new StandardItemExistanceVerifier( new StandardItemRetriever() );
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. While I ended up utilizing my solution below in the short term, I plan to refactor to something along these lines soon. Thanks for the help and the illustrative sample code!

Answer (score 0):

> the validator will receive the IItemExistenceVerifier and will not know whether it uses a cache or not.

That's why you have an interface - to hide implementation details. That's fine.

DoodadValidator should not care about caching, as well as IItemExistenceVerifier. It's only StandardCachedItemExistenceVerifier responsibility to work just like any other verifier, but with cache.

How to do it? Method ItemExists should work as follows:

```
public bool ItemExists( string itemToCheck )
{
    // Firstly checking if the item is already in the cache
    if( this.cache.ItemExists( itemToCheck ) )
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Trying to load the item into the cache. If it doesn't exist, returning false
    return this.cache.tryLoadItem( itemToCheck );
}
```

Comment: I agree, but my struggle is that the the doohickey is what has the items, and since I need to basically search and say "are any of these items existing?" as part of validation that lends the validator to need to tell the verifier about the list of items it needs it to verify the existence of.  Perhaps "cache" is the problem term here. Really I'm just pre-validating a batch and then hitting it once instead of for each item

Answer (score 0):

The following is one answer (I think?) and the one I'll go with if I don't see anything better come along:

- I created an Interface, `ICacheFillable<T>`
- I set my verifier to implement `ICacheFillable<string>`
- In my processor, right before I loop through all the items to validate them, I call a `FillCacheForVerifier()` method.
- The `FillCacheForVerifier()` method looks like this:

  ```
  private void FillItemVerifierCache()
  {
      // Attempt to cast the verifier 
      var potentiallyCacheableVerifier =
          _DoodadValidator.ItemVerifier as ICacheFillable<string>;

      // if the item is cacheable 
      if (potentiallyCacheableVerifier != null)
      {
          // get all of the items into a list of strings
          var cacheItems = from x in _doodad.Items select x.StringProperty;

          // fill the cache with the items
          potentiallyCacheableVerifier.FillCache(cacheItems);
      }

  }
  ```

So the end result is that it will only fill the cache if the item being passed in fulfills the ICacheFillable interface of its choosing.

If it doesn't strike folks as a good idea (and I'm by no means convinced), then hopefully it will at least help illustrate what I think my problem is.